# Are iOS app clips launchable from an url?

Tags: ios14, apple-appclips

Are iOS app clips launchable from an URL?

The Apple description says that the QR code embeds an encrypted URL to access the clips. Is it possible to use directly that link like with deep links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are iOS app clips launchable from an URL?

From iOS 17 and onwards, it's possible to launch App Clips from anywhere in the OS.

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10178?time=312

You can also use notes app and save URL from code snippet there on iOS 17+

https://appclip.apple.com/id?p=com.test.App.Clip

It will launch App Clip Card on link click :)

Comment: You can also find your App Clip's link in App Store Connect > iOS App (1.0.0 or whatever) > App Clip section > "Default App Clip Link".  Then you can add on any other URL params you want.  Only downside is it uses an Apple domain (vs your own), so a) it looks less branded, and b) what do you do for Android - because in your app, you probably want 1 URL structure that people can share universally?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, URLs can only be opened from Safari Smart App Banner. I managed to do that. Apple states in their forums that it is also possible from QR codes.

Looks like you can't just click a link - like in Universal Link - and the App Clip Card will show up.

Comment: After verfication, you are right I complete the answer with the apple developer doc : Users launch app clips by performing one of the following invocations:

Scanning an NFC tag or visual code at a physical location, 

Tapping a location-based suggestion from Siri Suggestions, 

Tapping a link in the Maps app, 

Tapping a Smart App Banner on a website, 

Tapping a link that someone shares in the Messages app (as a text message only)https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/developing_a_great_app_clip/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you can set up invocation URLs in App Store Connect and when the system opens a registered URL your App Clip should launch.

You can learn more in [this WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10146/) and from [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/configuring_your_app_clip_s_launch_experience).

Comment: I also understand that invocation URLs are set up in App Store Connect and not hard-coded is so that you can add/edit them without having to submit a new version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

When a user shares a link to a site that displays a smart banner configured for AppClip, then only message will present a banner that will invoke an App Clip.